# Date appears to be changing time zone from daylight to standard upon calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery range slider that is supposed to increase and decrease the date range by a week with each value.  When incrementing past a certain point (November 1st in my example) the time zone changes from daylight to standard.  I assume it has something to do with the way I'm calculating the new date but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

I calculate it with:

```
new Date(minDate.getTime() + (sliderValue * 7) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Here's an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aedryan/f4pvg84e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually working fine. The reason it changes after November 1 is because we switch from Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) to Eastern Standard Time on that date - in both cases you are representing the eastern time zone. Btw, for the future this is a nice way of adding days to a date:

```
/**
 * extends the functionality of the Date() object to include a function called addDays that adds days to
 * a javascript date based on an integer
 * @param days
 * @returns {Date}
 */
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days){

  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
};
```

Comment: One relevant thing here is that timezone of the client is used automatically.  So this isn't an EDT/EST specific bug but rather a general DST bug.  European users would see different results to US users because we put our clocks back a week earlier.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ that's a good point - working with time zones is definitely a pain in JS.

Comment: Got it, it all makes sense now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were calculating days by millisecond. However, November 1st was in fact day light savings (welcome to the wonderful world of time culture). As a result your times are off by 1 hour and that means you count 23 hours for one day and only get +6.

As opposed to making these changes by millisecond, simply add the days. This can be done easily in JavaScript as when the days extend past the amount available that month it just returns the adjusted date. That means you can use this for your newDate forumla

```
var newDate = new Date(2015, 7, 23+(ui.value*7));
```

Which looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/u2h261ka/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.